# Transforming Form Field to Object on Submit

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm rather new to Play Framework so I hope this is intelligible.

How can I tell play to map a form element to an Object field in the Form's class?

I have a form with a select dropdown of names of objects from my ORM.  The values of the dropdown items are the ID field of the ORM objects.

The form object on the Java side has a field with the type of the ORM object, and a setter taking a string and translating it to the object, but on form submission I only get a form error "Invalid Value" indicating the translation is not taking place at all.

My template has a form component:

```
@helper.select(
    createAccountForm("industry"),
    helper.options(industries)
)
```

Where `industries` is defined in the template constructor by : `industries: Map[String, String]`
and consists of ID strings to User-Readable names.

My controller defines the class:

```
public static class CreateAccountForm {
    public String name;
    public Industry industry;

    public void setIndustry(String industryId) {
        this.industry = Industry.getIndustry(Integer.parseInt(industryId));
    }
}
```

EDIT: I was doing the setter in the class because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743404/how-to-bind-form-field-to-an-object-in-play-2-framework) indicated to do so, but that didn't work.

EDIT2: 
Turns out the setter method was totally not the way to go for this.  After banging my head a bit on trying to get an annotation working, I noticed the Formatters.SimpleFormatter and tried that out.  It worked, though I don't understand why the extra block around it is necessary.

Global.java:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {


// Yes, this block is necessary; no, I don't know why.
{
    Formatters.register(Industry.class, new Formatters.SimpleFormatter<Industry>() {

        @Override
        public Industry parse(String industryId, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
            return Industry.getIndustry(Integer.parseInt(industryId));
        }

        @Override
        public String print(Industry industry, Locale locale) {
            return industry.name;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Play is binding the form to an object for you when you use it like described in the documentation: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaForms

So your controller should look like:

```
 Form<models.Task> taskForm = form(models.Task.class).bindFromRequest();
 if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
     return badRequest(views.html.tasks.create.render(taskForm));
 }
 Task task = taskForm.get();
```

The task object can have a `Priority` options list. And you use it in the form (view) like:

```
@select(editForm("priority.id"), options(Task.priorities),  'class -> "input-xlarge", '_label -> Messages("priority"), '_default -> Messages("make.choice"), 'showConstraints -> false, '_help -> "")
```

Notice that I am using `priorities.id` to tell play that a chosen value should be binded by a priority ID. And of course getting the priorities of the Tasks:

```
public static Map<String, String> priorities() {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> prioritiesList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    List<Priority> priorities = Priority.getPrioritiesForTask("task");
    for (Priority orderPrio : priorities) {
        prioritiesList.put(orderPrio.getId().toString(), orderPrio.getDescription());
    }
    return prioritiesList;
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work if play was binding the object correctly, but it wasn't.  I did find though that I just needed to add a Formatter for the Industry class.